# Google Fit API Alternative

Tags: watchos, sony-smartwatch

I'm developing an Android app that utilizes smartwatch health data, such as heart rate and stress levels. Currently, I'm using the Google Fit API, which provides a unified way to access this data from various smartwatches with different operating systems. However, I've learned that Google Fit API support will end by late 2024.

I'm looking for alternative APIs or solutions that could offer similar functionality. The ideal solution would allow me to access health data from multiple smartwatch brands and operating systems without needing to integrate each brand's individual API.

Are there any established alternatives to Google Fit API that provide broad smartwatch compatibility? If not, what strategies could I employ to manage data collection from multiple device-specific APIs in an efficient way?

Comment: Seeking recommendations like this is off topic.  Please review the rules and guidelines before posting.